# Applying Layout to Default Homepage Using Object Model

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, page-layout, object-model

I've This Code to Add Page from Page Layout

```
 using (SPSite site = new SPSite(w.Url))
        {
            using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
            {
                PublishingSite pSite = new PublishingSite(site);
                SPContentType ctype = pSite.ContentTypes["Page"];
                PageLayoutCollection pageLayouts = pSite.GetPageLayouts(ctype, true);
                PageLayout pageLayout = pageLayouts["/_catalogs/masterpage/gallery.aspx"];
                PublishingWeb pWeb = PublishingWeb.GetPublishingWeb(web);
                PublishingPageCollection pPages = pWeb.GetPublishingPages();


                //
                try
                {
                    PublishingPage pPage = pPages.Add("photogallery.aspx", pageLayout);

                    SPListItem newpage = pPage.ListItem;
                    newpage["Title"] = "Gallery" + " | " + web.Name;
                    newpage.Update();
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                    Console.WriteLine("Gallery Page Successfuly created for " + web.Name);

                    newpage.File.CheckIn("all looks good");
                    newpage.File.Publish("all looks good");
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                    Console.WriteLine("The Gallery Page is Already Created for this site! You can Recreate It");  
                }

            }
        }
```

How can i apply Layout to existing Default homepage Site/subsite/default.aspx ?

```
pWeb.DefaultPage //returns the Default.aspx page
```

but i dont know how to change its layout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default.aspx page is a web part page. You can change the layout of a layout page and not the webpart page. If you requirement is to set a layout page as the home page of site, then you can use following code sample:

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://YourSite"))
{
    using(SPWeb web = web = site.OpenWeb("SubWeb"))
    {
        SPFolder rootfolder = web.RootFolder;
        rootfolder.WelcomePage = "Pages/Home.aspx";
        rootfolder.Update();
    }    
}
```

**UPDATE**

To update the "SharePoint Server Publishing" Feature in all subsites of a site collection, use follwoing PS code:

```
$site = Get-SPSite "http://aissp2013/sites/team"
foreach ($web in $site.AllWebs)
{
    $FeatureID = "94c94ca6-b32f-4da9-a9e3-1f3d343d7ecb" 
    Write-Host "Enabling feature in $web"
    Enable-SPFeature -Identity $FeatureID -Confirm:$false -Url $web.url -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
}
Write-Host "Finished!"
```

Comment: The 'Pages' Document Libarary is missing :(

Comment: it thew that exception

Comment: I found that server publishing feature is disabled on all sub sites how can i enable them on all sub sites ?

Comment: Use a PowerShell code to loop through all sub sites and update the feature.

Comment: i used This script can u take a look ?
its loading for very long time no sigle writeLine in powershell

http://www.sharepointfix.com/2011/01/enumerate-site-collections-subsites-and.html

Comment: @AhmedAborady, see my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks Very Much @Nadeem Yousuf i really Appreciate your help 
maybe i get no answers but you coz my questions little stupid and newbie so Thanks for your patience :D